# Как лучше верстать?

Tags: html, css

Друзья, сейчас верстаю макет. Опыта не много. Хотел узнать, как лучше будет сверстать конкретный блок. С помощью таблицы или дивами, но с применением display [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте вопрос свой вариант вёрстки и поясните, с чем связано требование `с применением display`.

Comment: Выглядит таблицей, почему бы не использовать таблицу?

Comment: согласен с предыдущим оратором - всё что является таблицей - нужно верстать таблицей )

Answer (score 2):

Я может и не правильно сделал , но вроде похоже

```css
.table{
 display:table;
 margin:auto;
}
.table-cell{
 display:table-cell;
 max-width:150px;
 min-width:150px;
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 font-size:12px;
 position:relative;
}
.ch{
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Название</h2>
<div class="table"> 
  <div class="table-cell"> 
    Рейс
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Вылет
 </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Прилёт
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
    В пути
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Самолёт
 </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Класс
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table"> <!--2-->
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   <input type="checkbox" class="ch"> SN-120
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   08:50 Чита
 </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   11:50 Домодедово
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
    9:00
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Боинг 737-800
 </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Э / 4
  </div>
</div>
<div class="table"> <!--2-->
  <div class="table-cell"> 
     <input type="checkbox" class="ch">  SN-120
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   08:50 Чита
 </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   11:50 Домодедово
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
    9:00
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Боинг 737-800
 </div>
  <div class="table-cell"> 
   Э / 4
  </div>
</div>
```

ссылка на [песочницу](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/YpmGxz?editors=110)  мне кажется что лучше

Comment: Зачем таблицу верстать дивами?

Comment: @Николай, чтобы адаптировать потом для мобильных. Например выстроить все друг под другом. Это очень хороший способ!

Comment: @Elena, не соглашусь с вами: это в принципе неудобное решение если много столбцов или ячеек. В данном случае лучше сделать горизонтальный скролл таблицы )

Comment: @Николай  на любом принципе хоть css table хоть блоками можно адаптировать под мобилку , у меня не было задачи для этого

Comment: @Николай, может быть и лучше, но если заказчик сказал что должно быть без скролла, то table-cell отличное решение. И никаких сложностей, как по мне.

Comment: Но и я не буду спорить, что таблицы должны быть таблицами!)